# History of ‘smile one's thanks’

Tags: history, phrase-origin

I'm interested to know when the actual phrase *smile one's thanks* was first registered in the English language, as well as *smile agreement* and *nod agreement*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OED gives three citations from Shakespeare for ***smile*** as a *transitive* verb...

> 1598   *Love's Labour's Lost v. ii.*
>    Some Dick That smyles, his cheeke in yeeres.
>
> 1609   *Pericles xxi. 127*
>    Thou doest looke like patience..smiling extremitie out of act.
>
> 1616 *Twelfth Night (1623) iii. ii.*
>    He does smile his face into more lynes, then is in the new Mappe.

---

OED's first citation for transitive ***nod*** is a 1522 translation of *Virgil's Æneid*, but it's not until over a century later that we see it used with anything other than *head[s]* as the object (1667, in *Dryden's Annus Mirabilis* - "He..nods at every house his threatning fire.").

---

OP's specific pairings *smile thanks* and *nod agreement* are trivial variants once the possibility of transitive usage is established within the language.

Comment: Very useful information! Smiling my thanks)) And how do you access OED - free or for a charge?

Comment: @Natalya: I get free access to OED through my public library card, but it's an eye-watering $295 pa if you have to take out a personal subscription.

Comment: Oh, I see... Nevertheless, a million thanks for your commentary)))

Answer (score 3):

In 'An historical syntax of the English language' [Vol 1 part 3] by F T Visser, a section dealing with these 'pseudo-report' verbs (and novel quotative verbs) is found:

Transitivisation may also have been furthered by the fashion which set in in later modern English – especially in novels – of treating verbs expressing human and animal sounds (such as *bellow*, *coo* and *groan*) as well as verbs such as *smirk*, *smile* and *persist* as if they were synonyms of *say* by giving them the quoted words as object [ie using novel quotative verbs].

From

> She smiled “I don’t believe you”

and

> He grunted “I thank you”

to

> She smiled disbelief

and

> He grunted his gratitude

[so novel quasi-report structures] was only a step.  [tidied]

Comment: Very useful information! Thank you! If I could, I would smile my thanks)))