# Word that means 'speak comfortingly/reassuringly'?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

Is there an English word that means "to speak in a manner intended to comfort or reassure"? For example:

> "Oh, honey, what's wrong?" her mother ____ed.

I keep wanting to say it is "croon", but Wiktionary [insists](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/croon#English) that "croon" means "sing", and Thesaurus.com [seems to agree](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/croon) based on what it considers acceptable synonyms.

"Cosset" is also in the neighborhood, but doesn't seem to imply *speaking*. "Console" is even closer, but doesn't really fit *asking a question* in such manner a la the above example.

(An answer *with references* that agrees with my intuition and can demonstrate that my sources are wrong is also acceptable.)

Edit: To clarify, an *ideal* answer would be a word that describes *tone*, such as "shout", "whisper", "hiss", etc., rather than a word that describes *intent* such as "placate", "assuage", etc. (the latter of which would otherwise be good answers).

Comment: I think you're looking for "cooed" - often used in this sense.

Comment: *"solaced"*, *"soothed"*...?

Comment: @Oldbag No way. See the meaning and usage.

Comment: Nothing wrong with ***comforted*** -- I would myself prefer that word. Look it up. Good Luck.

Comment: @Kris - Sorry but, I can vaguely remember multiple instances from children's books and poetry - from when I was little. I'm on my way to work now, but maybe a kind soul with good references will help me out?

Comment: The specimen question you give indicates that the answer must be a quotative verb (one that can be used in a speech tag). Is this a definite requirement? Note that 'speak', in your title, isn't a quotative verb.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I'm not sure I fully understand what a "quotative verb" is, but I *think* "yes"...

Comment: One that can be used in a speech tag, showing who gave the utterance (and increasingly nowadays, in what manner). A whole range of novel-ish quotative verbs (see ['He nodded his head "Yes" ...'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/133778/he-nodded-his-head-yes-she-shook-her-head-no/165866#165866); also useful is ['History of "smile one's thanks" '](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227685/history-of-smile-ones-thanks/227702#227702)) are now acceptable, at least in some registers.

Answer (score 1):

[Soothed](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/soothed)

> to bring comfort, solace, or reassurance to

Answer (score 0):

Something like

"Oh, honey, what's wrong?" her mother asked gently.

could also get your message across quite nicely.

I agree with one of the comments above that "cooed" could also work. If you look at the definition from the Oxford Dictionary (https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/coo), it fits with what you are trying to convey. That is, the mother speaking with a soft (and comforting) tone.

Comment: I would otherwise agree with this answer except that it doesn't meet [tag:single-word-requests].

Answer (score 0):

### [Coo](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/coo#Verb)

(Suggested by [Oldbag](/users/99368/oldbag).)

> 1. To make a soft murmuring sound, as a pigeon.
> 2. To speak in an admiring fashion, to be enthusiastic about.

The first definition is plausible, at least. The second is a bit off. Still, this may be the closest I've found so far.

### [Chirr](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chirr#Verb)

> To make the prolonged trilling sound of an insect.

Well, sort-of plausible.

---

More ideas in line with [Justin's answer](/a/521886/216063):

- [Assuage](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/assuage#Verb)
- [Gentle](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/gentle#Verb)
- [Hush](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hush#Verb)
- [Lull](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lull#Verb)
- [Temper](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/temper#Verb)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try:

"Oh, honey, what's wrong?" her mother lissed.

Seems to be a bit antiquated though, but it seems onomatopoeic enough and also fits the meaning.

Comment: I had to look up the word https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/liss#English. It's not a *bit* antiquated, it's proper obsolete. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&filter=en_dictionary&dictionary=en&query=liss) (formerly Oxford Online Dictionaries) doesn't list it. If I heard that being uttered I would think the verb was *lisped*.

Answer (score 0):

ENCOURAGINGLY

adverb. /ɪnˈkʌrɪdʒɪŋli/ /ɪnˈkɜːrɪdʒɪŋli/ ​in a way that gives somebody support, courage or hope.

Comment: Where's the definition taken from?

Comment: Again, this does not fit OP's frame '"Oh, honey, what's wrong?" her mother ____ed.'